# Async.waterfall within a for-loop not iterating properly

Tags: javascript, node.js, for-loop, asynchronous

This is obviously an extremely simplified code snippet, but my code base is being held up with something that this example is set to mimic.

When I try to log the current for-loop index from within an async.waterfall function, I get 2. 2 is the number of total elements in my array, but of course the indices should be 0 and 1. I've effectively used async.MAP within a for-loop in the past, so I'm not sure why this async function is not working. Thanks for any help with this matter or on the topic of nesting async-library functions.

```
var objects = [
    {objectName: "hello",
        objectPurposes: ["demo"]},
    {objectName: "goodbye",
        objectPurposes: ["demo", "fun"]}];

for (var i=0; i<objects.length; i++){
    async.waterfall([
        function(callback){
            console.log(i);
        }
    ])
}
```

Comment: [async-waterfall](https://github.com/caolan/async#waterfalltasks-callback) accepts an array as first param, which will be your objects array, to iterate it over length of array.

Comment: the first param of async-waterfall is the array of tasks, isn't it?

Comment: I think Ravi meant `async.forEach`.

Answer (score 1):

Well,the value of i would have changed by the time the async.waterfall completes its processing.If you want to retain the value of i,you could wrap it around a IIFE.

```
var objects = [{
    objectName: "hello",
    objectPurposes: ["demo"]
}, {
    objectName: "goodbye",
    objectPurposes: ["demo", "fun"]
}];

for (var i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {
    (function(i) {
        async.waterfall([
            function(callback) {
                console.log(i);
            }
        ])
    })(i);
};
```

I would much rather use obj.shift() and wrap the async.waterfull under a recursive function for such a purpose though.
http://book.mixu.net/node/ch7.html go through this,its really helpfull.